# JSF class not found bean annotation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I having problems with beans in xhtml file, they are not being recognized or instantiated, I tried to use managed-bean on faces-config file but it not working as well.

```
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(value="loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean
```

on my xhtml file I am doing something like this

```
<c:set var="log" scope="session" value="#{loginBean.logged}"/>
```

but I am getting thins exception (this is a just a small part of the exception which I think is pointing the problem)

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /buy/buy.xhtml @96,78 listener="#{loginBean.logged}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2603)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2187)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2135)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:289)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:247)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:726)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:726)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can someone help me please because I am not understanding why it is happening. I am not using maven, I am using just Tomee with JSF 2.1 and I have all necessary jars in the lib folder. I was reading things about this problem and people say that the problem is with the projectname/src where all the classes should be. I am also showing my Java Build Path Source and my project structure

[Java Build Path Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11TWD.png)

[Project Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUOFk.png)

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

Your bean is not implementing the interface Serializable and it should be `@ManagedBean(name="loginBean")` instead of `@ManagedBean(value="loginBean")`, but in this case imo that name is redundant since it has the same name as the class.

Answer (score 0):

You import should be

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Many of these 'basic' issues have already been asked in one way or another and have a corresponding answer. Searching for these duplicate is much appreciated to keep the number of  questions clean...